# Digitise a circle around a point in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, point

In previous versions of QGIS I used the Intersect It plugin for drawing circles around a point with a specified radius.

However, I cannot see a way to digitise a circle around a point in QGIS 3.  I have tried using the new shape digitising tools, but these do not allow to centre the circle on a point (at least, not that I can see).

I have seen suggestions about buffering the points by a certain distance, but this seems quite a long-winded way of merely drawing a shape.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would argue that running the buffer tool is easier than manually digitizing a circle around a point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Shape Digitizing Toolbar's "Add Circle by a Centre Point and Another Point" tool combined with the Advanced Digitizing tool's distance option.

[image]

But to be honest I don't find buffering to be long winded at all and I usually go with that method.

Comment: I would enable snapping too

Comment: I would strongly advise against that https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21144 ;-)

Comment: @JochenSchwarze good catch. I'm glad to see there's an issue posted about this, it's been killing me. Been meaning to report it. EDIT: Although it works fine with tooltips turned off.

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks, that's a lot clearer now :)